# iOS How to check if currently on phone call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, phone-call

I have look around and all I can find is checking the callState of CTCallCenter. However, this works by listening to an event - which depending on whether the application is active/suspended/resumed the event can be raised at different time.

What I need is rather than listening to event and got told when call is connected, I want to decide myself when to ask if the call is connected.

Use case: When phone call is connected - user knows and will always click on the app icon, which will open the app. At this time I just want to run a quick function to check if currently on call or not.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `CTCallCenter` object has a `currentCalls` property which is an `NSSet` of the current calls. If there is a call then the `currentCalls` property should be != nil.

If you want to know if any of the calls is actually connected, then you'll have to iterate through the current calls and check the `callState` to determine if it is `CTCallStateConnected` or not.

Comment: ''CTCallCenter' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Replaced by CXCallObserver from CallKit.framework'

Answer (score 27):

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

-(bool)isOnPhoneCall {
    /*

     Returns TRUE/YES if the user is currently on a phone call

     */

    CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[[CTCallCenter alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (CTCall *call in callCenter.currentCalls)  {
        if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be functioning when building in Xcode 7 for iOS 9.x

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the answer ThomasW. I thought I would also post the code.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    CTCallCenter *ctCallCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    if (ctCallCenter.currentCalls != nil) 
    {
        NSArray* currentCalls = [ctCallCenter.currentCalls allObjects];
        for (CTCall *call in currentCalls)
        {   
            if(call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
            {
                // connected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could shorten this code a lot by using fast enumeration: `for (CTCall *call in ctCallCenter.currentCalls) {...}`. You don't need to check for `nil` or convert the set to an array.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, but I think that the correct way to do this from **iOS 10** is:

```
func checkForActiveCall() -> Bool {
    for call in CXCallObserver().calls {
        if call.hasEnded == false {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```