# Find if user is in a call or not?

Tags: ios, swift, phone-call

I wanted to see if a user was using the application and to see if they were in a phone call or not. I was following this link to see check if a user was in a phone call or not: [iOS How to check if currently on phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942334/ios-how-to-check-if-currently-on-phone-call). However, this looks like it's for Objective-C. I was wondering if there was a  Swift equivalent for this. This is my attempt:

```
    var currCall = CTCallCenter()
    var call = CTCall()

    for call in currCall.currentCalls{
        if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected{
            println("In call.")
        }
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem as if call has an attribute `.callState` like how it does in the previous example. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @Sam well I can't get my code to compile. The `.callState` attribute is not being recognized by the object `call` in the for loop above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update for Swift 2.2: you just have to safely unwrap `currCall.currentCalls`.

```
import CoreTelephony
let currCall = CTCallCenter()

if let calls = currCall.currentCalls {
    for call in calls {
        if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected {
            print("In call.")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Previous answer: you need to safely unwrap *and* to tell what type it is, the compiler doesn't know.

```
import CoreTelephony
let currCall = CTCallCenter()

if let calls = currCall.currentCalls as? Set<CTCall> {
    for call in calls {
        if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected {
            println("In call.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could cast `.currentCalls` to `Set<CTCall>` on the first line instead of casting every call separately.

Comment: The  CTCallCenter class/api is deprecated since iOS 10

Answer (score 13):

**iOS 10, Swift 3**

```
import CallKit

/**
    Returns whether or not the user is on a phone call
*/
private func isOnPhoneCall() -> Bool {
    for call in CXCallObserver().calls {
        if call.hasEnded == false {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: always get call.hasEnded == false if close app, open app then hasEnded = true

Answer (score 8):

Or, shorter (swift 5.1):

```
private var isOnPhoneCall: Bool {
    return CXCallObserver().calls.contains { $0.hasEnded == false }
}
```