# iOS How to detect call state in background?

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I'm trying to change button state depending on call state.
I used code from here to detect call state: [How to get a call event using CTCallCenter:setCallEventHandler: that occurred while the app was suspended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh)

And it works fine when app is in foreground. But it doesn't work in background at all. In documentation for `CTCallCenter.callEventHandler`:

> When your application resumes the active state, it receives a single
>   call event for each call that changed state—no matter how many state
>   changes the call experienced while your application was suspended. The
>   single call event sent to your handler, upon your application
>   returning to the active state, describes the call’s state at that
>   time.

But I don't get any call events when app resumes active. All I get is last saved call state when app was in foreground. How can I detect call state in background?

Here is my code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
  let callСenter = CTCallCenter()

    func block (call:CTCall!)
    {
        callState = String(call.callState)
        print(call.callState)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        //check for call state
        callСenter.callEventHandler = block

...

        return true
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(cameBackFromSleep),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
            object: nil
        )

        ...
    }

    func cameBackFromSleep()
    {
        self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        switch callState
        {
        case "CTCallStateConnected":
            print("callState: ", callState)
            self.textLabel.isHidden = true
            startBtnAnimation()
        case "CTCallStateDisconnected":
            print("callState: ", callState)
            self.textLabel.center.y += self.view.bounds.height
            self.textLabel.isHidden = false
            stopBtnAnimation()
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it! I used code from this answer: [Find if user is in a call or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915724/find-if-user-is-in-a-call-or-not)

I removed everything from `AppDelegate`, all job is done in `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(cameBackFromSleep),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
            object: nil
        )

...

    }

    private func isOnPhoneCall() -> Bool
    {
        let callCntr = CTCallCenter()

        if let calls = callCntr.currentCalls
        {
            for call in calls
            {
                if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected || call.callState == CTCallStateDialing || call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming
                {
                    print("In call")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        print("No calls")
        return false
    }

    func cameBackFromSleep()
    {

        self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        print("is on call", isOnPhoneCall())
        switch isOnPhoneCall()
        {
        case true:
            print("startBtnAnimation")
            startBtnAnimation()
            recordBtnIsPressed = true
        case false:
            print("stopBtnAnimation")
            stopBtnAnimation()
            recordBtnIsPressed = false
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Now it works fine. Not sure why `CTCallCenter` works so weird in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: This API is already deprecated since iOS 10. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcallcenter