# Can I detect if the System(iOS) is on Call using Call Kit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have developed a Video Calling application using Twilio Video SDK, I have a scenario where if the iPhone is on another call(Voice call) I need to detect it and send busy status(recipient on another call) to my application. Is there any way I can do this with CallKit

#### Currently what is happening?

If the recipient is on another call (Voice call), and my application calls the recipient both call goes on with microphone being used by voice call.

#### What I want?

Detect if system is on call(voice call) so that I can perform needed action based on this

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915724/find-if-user-is-in-a-call-or-not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find if user is in a call or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915724/find-if-user-is-in-a-call-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this link : [Find if user is in a call or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915724/find-if-user-is-in-a-call-or-not)

Also you can use CallKit and can combine logic to find many values :

```
func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {

   if call.hasEnded == true {
       print("CXCallState: Disconnected")
   }

   if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false {
       print("CXCallState: Dialing")
   }

   if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
       print("CXCallState: Incoming")
   }

   if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {
       print("CXCallState: Connected")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, by implementing `CXCallObserver` and using it's delegate method `callObserver(_ callChanged:)`

Another solution is to implement so called audio interruption notification function that will handle external audio interruptions that your application can respond to, like receiving an incoming call, alarms, etc.

**Steps**

First, add observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleInterruption(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: theSession)
```

And implement notification handler

```
func handleInterruption(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let value = (notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? NSNumber)?.uintValue,
        let interruptionType =  AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: value) else {
            return
        }
    switch interruptionType {
    case .began:
        // stop app audio here
        break
    case .ended:
        // resume app audio here
        break
    }
}
```

My advice to you is to use CallKit's CXCallObserver, since it responds well to external call events.